# Простая вбивалка для сайта

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, администрирование

Прошу прощения за столь легкий и простой вопрос, но... А где можно посмотреть простой пример вбивания инфы в таблицу, которая хранится в БД?

Пример `table`, есть столбцы `id text code`. Столбец `code` имеет только два значения - 1 или 2. Форма вбивалки.

- введите `text` (форма ввода текста)
- выберите `code` (выпадающий список выбора)

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method='post' action='submitter.php'>
<input type='text' name='text'>
<select name='code'>
 <option value='1'>1</option>
 <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' value='Отправить'>
</form>
```

Вот. А в файле `submitter.php` сам скрипт записи данных в БД (не забывай про проверку данных на корректность и безопасность). Сами введённые данные будут в переменных `$_POST['text']` и `$_POST['code']`.

Comment: а что прописать в submitter.php ?

Comment: @meravaz, в смысле? В поле формы на странице не вводятся буквы при нажатии клавиши, только символы?

Answer (score 0):

В `submitter.php` прописываете примерно следующее:

```
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table (text,code) VALUES (".$_POST["name"].",".$_POST["code"].")");
if ($result == true) {
echo "Информация занесена"; }
```

Только не забудьте подключиться к базе в начале, примерно так : )

```
$dbuser = "Логин";
$dbpass = "Пароль";
$dbname = "Имя базы";
$db = mysql_connect("localhost",$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$db);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает но... вводятся только цифры, даже `text` принимает только цифры, а я и `rext` и `code` хотел поменять на текст.